# Information needed on availability of RAID controllers that have hardware encryption capability

Tags: raid, encryption, hardware-raid

I am somewhat familiar with the RAID controller card offerings in Dell servers, such as PERC  H730P in their PowerEdge servers.  And also some of the LSI 9xxx series RAID controller cards, that allows RAID configuration of 8,16, or 24 SAS/SATA disks.

It was brought to my attention there now exists RAID controller cards that also have **hardware encryption**

which can then meet encryption requirements where one does not need to set up software encryption from within the operating system or use Self-Encryption Drives (SED's).

can someone point me in the right direction, if such a thing exists?

I am specifically interested in finding RAID controller cards that do hardware encryption, the type of controller card you would commonly find in medium to high end 2U are larger rack servers containing 8,16, or 24 SAS/SATA drives.

Comment: One problem is access to your data if the hardware ever fails.  Make sure you have the keys safely stored and there is some means of loading the keys on replacement hardware or using software to decrypt.

Answer (score 1):

We're very clear in our help pages that we don't do product/service recommendations - that said the majority of vendor-supplied disk controllers bought these days support full-array encryption, with, and sometimes without, SEDs. Certainly the majority of those sold by HPE, all of those sold by Cisco and several other companies support encryption - just read the specifications of the disk controller sold with your servers, if they support encryption it'll 'leap off the page'.

Answer (score 1):

November 2012: [Is there such thing as hardware encrypted raid disk?](https://serverfault.com/questions/449753/is-there-such-thing-as-hardware-encrypted-raid-disk)

current date: Sept. 14, 2018

tech brief **dated July 2018** from Microsemi, titled "Microsemi Adaptec SmartStorage maxCrypto: Superior Data-at-Rest Encryption"

> Microsemi’s evolutionary maxCrypto™ controller based encryption technology, available on the Microsemi SmartROC 3100 and SmartIOC 2100 controllers, is now also available on the industry's **first** readily available adapter, the 12 Gbps SmartRAID 3162 RAID Adapters

https://www.microsemi.com/product-directory/storage-ics/3689-raid-controllers

> The PM8205, PM8237, and PM8241 includes support for maxCrypto™ Controller Based Encryption - Industry's **only** data-at-rest controller-based encryption

July 26, 2018: http://www.thessdreview.com/tag/controller-based-encryption/

> The 3162-8i/e debuts as the industry’s **first** off-the-shelf 12Gbps SAS/SATA RAID adapter with maxCrypto™, which is a line rate controller-based encryption (CBE) solution, and provides superior security and flexibility compared to encryption solutions that are disk-based.

https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic

> Server Fault is for questions about managing information technology systems in a business environment.
>   If your question is about:
>
> **managing the hardware or software of servers**, workstations, **storage** or networks
>       tools used for administering, monitoring, or automating these
>       deployment to and management of third-party provided information technology platforms
>
> and is not about:
>       consumer workstations or networking (which belong on our sister site, Super User)
>       working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel
>       product, service, or learning material recommendations
>       product licensing inquiries or legal advice
>       career, salary, personnel, employment, or formal education
>       unauthorized use or misuse of IT systems